# Filling null with data flitering by other columns

Tags: fillna

Hi guys I have a question, how can I fillna() on columns filtering by other columns. For example, if I have missing values in "Cabin" and "Destination", I want to fill those null values in those 2 columns by using the same values of a row that have the same value in column "Last Name"

[image: 1]

I have no idea how to make this work

Answer (score 1):

This way also works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["a1", np.nan],
    "B": ["b1", "b1"]
})

df_drop = df.dropna()

df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(
    pd.Series(df["B"].values, index=df.index)
        .replace(df_drop.set_index("B")["A"])
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If missing values in "A", and used "B" column to fillna.

One method is use "mapping", see:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["a1", np.nan],
    "B": ["b1", "b1"]
})

df_drop = df.dropna()

df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(df["B"].map(dict(zip(df_drop["B"], df_drop["A"]))))
```

Hope someone can improve this code or propose better method.